# collect tx fees from a pallet

Tags: transactions, fee

Is there a way to send tx fees of a pallet to an account? Like transactions fees of pallet X is send to an account. We can split the global tx fees between treasury and other but we want to do it as a per pallet basis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely possible, but will require some of your own design and elbow grease to make work.

Specifically, you should look at the `trait OnChargeTransaction`: https://paritytech.github.io/substrate/master/pallet_transaction_payment/trait.OnChargeTransaction.html

You can see that `withdraw_fee` has a `call` input:

```rust
fn withdraw_fee(
    who: &T::AccountId,
    call: &T::RuntimeCall,
    dispatch_info: &DispatchInfoOf<T::RuntimeCall>,
    fee: Self::Balance,
    tip: Self::Balance
) -> Result<Self::LiquidityInfo, TransactionValidityError>;
```

With this, you should be able to see what call is triggering a fee payment to occur. When implementing this trait, you can have a match statement which detects which call is being executed, and then have special logic to handle the fees of that call.

Beyond this, you could also just design a specific fee system for specific pallets, since each pallet has full access to manipulate the balance of a user. There would be no need to touch the transaction fee pallet in this case, however these "extra" fees may be opaque to a user who is not aware of this.

Comment: Thank you Shawn.